# How to use functor as custom comparator in priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, functor

I am trying to create a functor as custom comparator for my priority_queue which takes in an unordered_map as a parameter for constructor. I am not sure how to call the functor when declaring the priority_queue as I am getting the error:

"Line 22: Char 48: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
priority_queue<string, vector, compareWords(wordFreq)> pq;"

```
   class compareWords{
        public:
        compareWords(unordered_map<string, int> &wordCounts): wordFreq(wordCounts){}
        bool operator()(string word1, string word2){
            if(wordFreq[word1] == wordFreq[word2]){
                return word1 < word2;
            }
            return wordFreq[word1] < wordFreq[word2];
        }
        private:
        unordered_map<string, int> wordFreq;
    };
    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
        vector<string> result;
        unordered_map<string, int> wordFreq;
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
            wordFreq[words[i]]++;
        }
        priority_queue<string, vector<string>, compareWords(wordFreq)> pq;
        for(auto& item: wordFreq){
            pq.push(item.first);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            result.push_back(pq.top());
            pq.pop();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR version:

```
priority_queue<string, vector<string>, compareWords> pq(compareWords{wordFreq});
```

## How we got there:

With the trivial solution, pass the comparator into `pq`'s constructor, you encounter the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and

```
priority_queue<string, vector<string>, compareWords> pq(compareWords(wordFreq));
                                       ^class goes here ^ object goes here
```

is a function definition. Yuck. Normally the solution to MVP is to use "uniform initialization"

```cpp
priority_queue<string, vector<string>, compareWords> pq{compareWords(wordFreq)};
                                                       ^                      ^
```

but this triggers `priority_queue`'s Initialization list constructor. Also yuck.

However, we can use the curly braces on `compareWords`'s construction instead

```cpp
priority_queue<string, vector<string>, compareWords> pq(compareWords{wordFreq});
                                                                    ^        ^
```

and avoid `priority_queue`'s initialization list constructor overload while not fooling the constructor into thinking we're declaring a function. Thank you to Caleth for pointing this trick out. I'd overlooked it.

Comment: why not `pq(compareWords{wordFreq});`?

Comment: Quite literally because it didn't occur to me.